# Find Big-O Estimate of $f(n) = n^3 + 4n^2 \log(n) + n + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

So to show the big-O complexity I'm trying to find a C and a K such that $f(n) \le C g(n)$ for all $n > k$

To start solving $f(n) = n^3 + 4n^2 \log(n) + n + 1$

Fix $k = 1$, so $n > 1$

$f(n) = n^3 + 4n^2 \log(n) + n + 1 \le n^3 + 4n^3 \log(n) + n^3 + n^3$

$f(n) = n^3 + 4n^2 \log(n) + n + 1 \le 3n^3 + 4n^3 \log(n)$

But I'm not sure what to do next or if I even did that last step right. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: $\log (n) \leq n $ for some  $n$ .

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$f(n) = n^3 + 4n^2 \log(n) + n + 1 \leq n^3 +4n^3+n^3+n^3$$

Comment: So $\leq 7n^3$  and $O(n^3)$ ? I'm confused on happened to the log though.

Comment: @Jamie, as I said in the comment use that  $\log(n) \leq n$.

Comment: @Jamie , you can prove it by induction if you are wondering how $\log(n) \leq n$ .

Comment: so would that make it $4n^3$ times n, which makes it $\leq n^3 + 4n^4 + n^3 + n^3$ ?

Comment: @Jamie, no. This bound is not tight. Start by the original function which has $n^2\log(n) \leq n^2 \cdot n = n^3$.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks!!